# Idempotence of absolute value: how to show $\big| |a| \big| = |a|$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, real-numbers, absolute-value

How to prove that $\big| |a| \big| = |a|$? I mean it is somehow obvious as squaring makes numbers positive and the square root is defined as a positive number, but I would appreciate a (long) answer.

Probably by stating that $\sqrt{a^2} = \sqrt{\left(\sqrt{a^2}\right)^2}$.

Comment: Does $\big| |a| \big|$ mean anything other than the absolute value of the absolute value?

Comment: If $\big| |a| \big|$ means $||a||$ then $|a| = a$ if $a\ge 0$ and it equals $-a$ if $a < 0$.  Now if $a \ge 0$ then $|a|=a\ge 0$.  And if $a < 0$ then $|a| =-a > 0$.  So either way $|a| \ge 0$.  so by *definition* $||a|| = |a|$ if $|a| \ge 0$.... which it does.

Comment: i really think it is a pitty to get a downvote since im new here. I am not able to ask any questions for 2 days...

Comment: That seems ridiculous.  Are you sure that's the case? I'm up voting to counter.

Comment: yeah unfortunately, stack exchange recommended me to revise my questions and not ask questions for 2 days..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically as $|m|$ is always positive then $||a||$ is the absolute value or a positive number.  And as absolute values maintain magnitude, it is a positive number with the same magintude as a positive number.  I.e. itself.

If you use a formal definition such as:

Definition 1:  If $a \in \mathbb R$ and and $a \ge 0$ then $|a| = a$.  If $a < 0$ then $|a|=-a$.

Immediate Proposition:  $|a| \ge 0$ always.

Proof:  If $a \ge 0$ then $|a|= a\ge 0$.  If $a < 0$ then $|a| = -a > 0$.

So if $|a| \ge 0$ (which is always true) then $||a|| = |a|$.  DOne.

Definition 2: If $a \in \mathbb C$ and if we accept that $a\overline a\in \mathbb R^+$ (see proof) then $|a| = \sqrt{a\overline a}$.

Acceptence proof that $a\overline a\in \mathbb R^+$: First if $a = e + di$ where $e,d$ are real then $a\overline a =(e+di)(e-di) = e^2 +edi - edi - d^2i^2 = e^2 -(-d^2) = e^2+d^2$.  $e^2$ and $d^2$ are both non-negative real numbers so $e^2 + d^2$ is too.

So $a\in \mathbb C$ then $|a| = k$ for some non-negative real number.  Then $|a| = k + 0i$ and $\overline {|a|} = k - 0i=k$ and $|a|\overline{|a|}= k*k=k^2$.  And so $||a|| = \sqrt{k^2} = k=|a|$ (because $k\ge 0$.)

Now there are a lot of basic axioms and propositions I have taken for granted:

I assume without verification that:  For any real $m$ that $m^2 \ge 0$; and that: for any real $m\ge 0$ there exists a unique non-negative real number that I call $\sqrt{m}$ so that $(\sqrt{m})^2= m$.

[It's trivial to verify that  if $k\ge 0$ then $\sqrt{k^2} =k$.  That follows as there is a unique number $\sqrt{k^2}$ so that $\sqrt{k^2}^2 = k^2$ and $k$ is such a number such that $k^2 = k^2$.  Since such a number is unique $\sqrt{k^2} = k$.]

....

You ask in comments how to verify that a negative times a negative is negative:

1) $0*m = 0$.  Pf: $0*m = (0+0)m = 0*m + 0*m$ so $0 = 0*m - 0*m = 0*m + 0*m - 0*m = 0*m$.

2) $-(ab)=(-a)b= a(-b)$.  $0b = (a + (-a))b = ab + (-a)b$ as $(-a)b = -(ab)$.  The rest is the same.

Axiom:  If $a< b$ then $a+c < b+c$ for all $c$.

3) If $ a> 0$ then $-a < 0$ and if $a< 0$ then $-a> 0$. Pf: $a> 0$ then $a+(-a) > 0 +(-a) $ so $0 > -a$.  Ther rest is the same.

Axiom: If $a < b$ and $c > 0$ then $ac < bc$.

4)positive times positive is positive:  Pf: Let $a > 0; b> 0$.  Then $ab > 0b =0$.

5) Positive times negative is negative.  Pf:  Let $a > 0$ and $b<0$ then $-b > 0$ so $a(-b)=-ab > 0$ and so $ab < 0$.

6) Negative times a negative is positive:  Pf:  Let $a < 0$ and $b< 0$ then $-a > 0$ and $-ab < 0$ and so $-(-ab) > 0$ and so $ab > 0$.....

Oops I forgot :

3 $\frac 12$) $-(-m) = m$. Pf:   $m+ (-m) = 0$ so $m = -(-m)$.

The final thing I took for granted was that if $k \ge 0$ then there exists a *unique* $a \ge 0$ so that $a^2= k$.  We call that $a$ the radical of $k$ or $\sqrt{k}$.

To prove that we need some definitions about the completenes of the real numbers and I'm not going to get into that heare.

Comment: thanks for the efforts

Answer (score 3):

Go by the basic definition of the modulus function.

$|x|=\begin{cases}x,&x\ge0\\-x,&x<0\end{cases}$

Since $|x|\ge0, \Big||x|\Big|=|x|$

Comment: ah ok we can do a substitution and write |x|=: z since z is greater 0 it stays z so ||x||=|x|. thanks great answer. i have a got another axiomatic question. how to prove that negative times negative is positive. i thought about this. any negative answer could be written an the inverse of a positive number. say a>0 => -a<0. -a*-a = --(a*a) = a*a . Prove be x a real number. --x = x add -x broth sides and applying definition of an inverse since --x is an inverse of -x => 0=0. Right ?

Comment: Depends on your axioms.  But if $a > 0$ then $0=a+(-a) > 0+(-a)=-a$ so $-a < 0$ is the first step.  We (probably) have an axiom that if $c>0; a<b$ then $ac<bc$ so $a>0;b>0$ means $ab>0*b=0$ and $a>0;b<0$ mean $ab<0$ and if finally if $a<0;b<0$ then $-a>0;b<0$ so $-ab<0$ and $ab > 0$.  (But this assumes: 1)$0*a=0$ 2) $(-a)b=-(ab)$ which will probably need to be proven.

Comment: If you have got another question, you should probably post it instead of asking in the comments. I'll be glad to help if I can. It is really hard to make out your arguments right now.

Comment: thanks a lot, new to the community and proud to see such an effort to help- amazing.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, $|x| = x$ when $x \ge 0$, and $|x| = -x$ when $x < 0$. Since $|a|$ is non-negative, $\big||a|\big| = |a|$.